# Is there a way to make the function keys on both sides of my keyboard do the same thing in windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I use a split keyboard and I would like to be able to use the right hand for the same shortcuts as my left with minimal movement. Right now this is not possible because the 'Alt-Gr' and 'Menu' keys (wich I never use) behave differently to the 'Alt' and 'Windows key'.

Is there a way to make the function keys on both sides of the keyboard do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), remap right Alt to left Alt key and disable the right sub-menu key:

```
RAlt::LAlt 
AppsKey::Return
```

Comment: +1 - Much clearer than mine, which has been removed.